# Where is the Article AccountedTime Set function in Otrs soap api?

Tags: java, web-services, api, soap, otrs

I want to create otrs articles(of specific tickets) via soap api. I also need to set the accounted time of the created otrs articles.

In the api docs I find only functions to DELETE or GET the accounted time.
Am I missing something? This cannot be true, right?

http://otrs.github.io/doc/api/otrs/stable/Kernel/System/Ticket/Article.pm.html

I'm using a Java soap client and otrs version 3.1 - 3.3.

Maybe someone also knows how to do that via the rest api of OTRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the docs a lot, I found the correct Api function.

It is in Kernel::System::Ticket:

```
    TicketAccountTime() account time to a ticket.

    my $Success = $TicketObject->TicketAccountTime(
        TicketID  => 1234,
        ArticleID => 23542,
        TimeUnit  => '4.5',
        UserID    => 1,
    );
```

http://otrs.github.io/doc/api/otrs/stable/Kernel/System/Ticket.pm.html

I find it kind of confusing that this function isn't in the Kernel::System::Ticket::Article module.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the SOAP API will be dropped in further releases. Try to use the Generic Interface instead.

regards